# Filling between intervals on plot based on pandas column value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have an example DataFrame:

```
df = 

segment       sample      data_value
first           1            28
first           2            53
first           3            19
second          4            50
second          5            39
second          6            61
third           7            22
third           8            49
third           9            34
```

I'd like to plot `data_value` vs. `sample` with plot shading (with the background of the plot indicating each segment with a different color. For example, from the bottom of the graph to the top, shading the background of the plot for the "first" segment as blue, "second" segment as green, etc. with the legend.

I can do:

```
plt.scatter(df['sample'], df['data_value'])
```

but am struggling on how to fill the backgrounds for each segment of the plot in a color-coded way to show the progression over time. Could I use `fill_between()` somehow?

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: You could try seaborn's scatter plot: `sns.scatter(data=df, x='sample', y='data_value', hue='segment')`.  `fill_between` doesn't seem to be an appropriate function here.  Maybe you could write some code involving `axhspan`, but it won't be very automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? As suggested by JohanC, you can use `axhspan` to create bands as shown below...

Note: I am assuming that the order of sample is ascending, so that the code will work...

```
plt.scatter(df['data_value'], df['sample'])
colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red']
start = 0
for i, segs in enumerate(df.segment.unique()):
    plt.axhspan(start, df[df.segment == segs]['sample'].max(), facecolor=colors[i], alpha=0.2)
    start=df[df.segment == segs]['sample'].max()
```

**Plot**

[image]